# Exporting AWS instance

Tags: command-line, export, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to export my Amazon EC2 instance to a my S3 bucket as a VMware image.

I have successfully set up Amazon CLI tools, added my credentials and can run commands.

I am using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExportingEC2Instances.html as documentation but it is not working as expected. For one thing, this documentation states that "ec2-create-instance-export-task" is the init command to export an instance, but it is actually "aws ec2 create-instance-export-task" as I found after some fiddling. Also, the instance id argument appears to be "--instance-id" rather than "instance_id".

I have not had any luck finding up to date documentation as to how I need to enter the other parameters like "target_environment" and "s3_bucket", but I can tell you that doing what is in Amazon's docs isn't working for me.

Has anyone done this recently who can help? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-instance-export-task.html

Here is the correct documentation for anyone else that has this issue since it took me an hour of digging to find.

Comment: The doc you provided is referring to the 'aws' command which is found in the AWSCLI, not the same as the ec2-api-tools. Amazon should really provide the difference between the two.

Comment: @Clocker you are right - the ec2-api-tools package is practically deprecated and you should stick to the newer AWS CLI. Notice in https://aws.amazon.com/items/351?externalID=351 that the last update happened in July 2015.